# Find the commands that jvm was started with during run time (1.6.0_12)

Tags: jvm, jvm-arguments

Full story:
I am trying to start up an instance of hudson with a larger memory allocation and I'm currently using scripts owned by root that I can't modify directly to pass arguments. However the script currently passes the $JAVA_ARGS variable when starting up the service. I have exported the required parameters to JAVA_ARGS but the application still appears to be bound by the old memory restrictions.

Question:
Is there a way to find out which command line parameters were used to start up the instance. More specifically I'm looking to find the values that were passed (if any) to Xmx and Xms.

```
java version "1.6.0_12"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_12-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.2-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching I came about a pretty simple solution (which I'm a little embarrassed to have missed for so long). You can see the command line to any command running in linux with ps, as long as you pass the correct flags. I just made a call to `ps -fHu hudson` and was able to see the full command line call to java which showed the passed in parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can export $JAVA_ARGS, maybe you can override $PATH to trick the script to run another program instead of the JVM, which could be a program that simply writes its arguments somewhere.

Comment: The script is referring to a specific version of Java so I don't have the ability to redirect execution.

Comment: Perhaps you could copy the script, then, and run an edited version under similar conditions.

Comment: Or you may be able to monitor the command via operating system utilities, e.g. ps in Unix-like OSs.

Sorry for the beside-the-issue answers, but I don't think there is a way to access the JVM parameters from Java. You may be able to do something in C code, invoked via JNI, but then you are outside of Java, so exactly what to do depends on the exact environment on your machine.